# Empty mask erosion on an empty image yields white

Tags: opencv

Given the following code:

```
const A = cv.matFromArray(10, 10, cv.CV_8UC1, new Array(100).fill(0));
const B = cv.matFromArray(2, 2, cv.CV_8UC1, new Array(4).fill(0));

cv.erode(A, A, B);
```

OpenCV generates the following output (minus the borders, only there for clarity):

[image]

Why is that? Shouldn't the output be fully dark, same as the input?

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of two things.

First, the kernel you're using is all zeros. If you're doing erosion you probably want it filled with ones.

Second, you're using a kernel with even number size. There's no center with a kernel like that.

When I tried replicating your results in python, it only happened when both of these things were true. That upper-left border you're seeing is half the size of your kernel (a 100x100 kernel will create a 50 px border).

Edit: This is the code I used. It's python, but the results should be true in c++ as well.

Mask with Ones kernel (200x200 kernel on a 200x200 image)

[image]

Mask with Zeros kernel

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# create blank image
res = (200, 200);

# kernel
size = 200;
ones = np.ones((size,size), np.uint8);
zeros = np.zeros((size,size), np.uint8);

# mask
ones_mask = np.zeros(res, np.uint8);
zeros_mask = np.zeros(res, np.uint8);

# erode
ones_mask = cv2.erode(ones_mask, ones, iterations = 1);
zeros_mask = cv2.erode(zeros_mask, zeros, iterations = 1);

# show
cv2.imshow("One", ones_mask);
cv2.imshow("Zero", zeros_mask);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```